# Triaxial accelerometer tilt compensation

Tags: embedded, accelerometer, microcontroller

I have a board which provides acceleration values of a triaxial accelerometer (X, Y, Z: Y is the up vector). I want to get the acceleration direction in the XZ-plane. But the board may be mounted with a tilt. Can I compensate the tilt and how would I do that? I appreciate any hint. It would be nice if someone could point me into the right direction.

Comment: simple trig: if you mount on a tilt, you'll get acceleration in any axes which are NOT orthogonal to the acceleration direction.

Comment: If you do a "long enough" running average of the three accelerometers' results, you should have a vector that is 9.8 m/s "down" (average acceleration must be 0 in all directions except down, basically).  

Subtract "down" from your "instantaneous" results (probably a "short enough" running average to filter out noise), then rotate your remainder to be in line with a unit vector of "down".   That ought to give the "true" acceleration.

I'd put this as an answer, but the rotate part is a bit beyond my casual math recall, but hopefully that's some ideas to get you moving.

Comment: @RussSchultz Sounds like a problematic solution really. I posted one approach to such an "adaptive" system, but I think it will end up far too complex. And naturally you _can't_ just do a "long enough moving average", that's a very naive digital filter, average calculations will not be meaningful at all. Depending on use-case of course, but there's no reason why you should do moving average even in the event where the accelerometer remains mostly "resting". To begin with, you can filter out all samples that aren't close to 1G.

Comment: @lundin The filters (long, to detect gravity; short to filter out noise) need to have time constants that are appropriate for the application.   If it's meant to measure a device that's mostly stable, but with unknown initial and 'slowly' changing orientation, it works fine with 'long' being a few seconds and 'short' being <.1s.  It certainly works better than an initial calibration and then ignoring tilt in almost any application I can think of.  If your device rapidly changes orientation, or spends significant time in free fall, then you've got a completely different class of problem.

Comment: @RussSchultz Main remark is how moving average could ever be a relevant filter for this. Samples too far from 1G are noise. Why would I want those to impact my result? Samples where the sum of the coordinates is 1G but some of the coordinates are extreme, compared to the other samples, are also noise. Why would I want that to impact my result? Just remove them entirely, rather than having them make the result inaccurate by influencing the moving average.

Comment: @lundin I'm sorry you don't see the relevance, but it is there.  A higher order filter would be better, but for a first pass "getting started" answer, it's perfectly valid.   It certainly would be no less valid or error prone than a one time calibration (which is what you suggest in your answer).   Also, throwing out samples based on testing is a good way to introduce offset to your answers.   Trying to be "smart" about signal processing usually ends up in a spaghetti mess that is wrong.

Comment: @RussSchultz Well as it would happen, I'm speaking from real-word experience. I once developed a product that uses the calibration method. It has been out in production for many years now. The products are accurate and there has been no need for re-calibration, even of those units that have been used in the field for many years. The only theoretical issue is mechanical shocks that would affect the position of the accelerometer. In this case, it is a MEMS IC mounted on PCB, inside a hand-held device which is treated very roughly. Yet mechanical shocks have not been a quality problem at all.

Comment: Given that real-world experience of an identical case, I don't really see the merit of a product which doesn't use calibration. I only see needless complexity and bug potential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calibrate all accelerometer products so that they know what's normally the down direction. Based on your calibration, you get the true (x,y,z) coordinates in relation to the gravity component. The calibration values have to be added/subtracted from each accelerometer read.

Alternatively (and less professionally), you could make some sort of adaptive system which continuously saves the (x,y,z) coordinates whenever there is a total acceleration of 1G +/- margins. You can then apply a median filter to the sorted samples and hopefully you'll get the real coordinates of (x,y,z) corresponding to the gravity component. In order for this to be reliable, you'd have to implement some kind of AI, so that the program learns over time and stores the likely coordinates in NVM. Otherwise the program would always fail each time you get a use case where the total acceleration is 1G in any direction.

Comment: This answer is usefull to me. It indicated that I didn't understand the original problem and thus I will have to do some more thinking. Thanks anyway.